# Spring MVC GET Request Logging

Tags: spring, rest, web-services, http

I have a Spring Boot/Spring MVC REST app that has a GET mapping endpoint for ex.

```
@GetMapping(value = "/person")
public ResponseEntity<Person> getPerson(@RequestParam final String personID)
{
    //service call for a person
    return new ResponseEntity.ok(personObj);
}
```

I am using PostMan to hit the endpoint and I have the spring boot jar running and something I noticed was that every PUT and POST method is logged but when it came to GET requests, they were not logged. The only time I got a GET in the running spring boot server logs was if I hit the wrong endpoint path for i.e localhost:8080/personn (misspelling) the log would show the URL with the requestparam value appended to the URL like  `"GET /personn?personID=123 HTTP/1.1" 404 - "-" "PostmanRuntime`

It seems like successful GET calls are not logged but unsuccessful GET calls are logged. Is this normal behavior?

If personID was sensitive data then I should probably use POST?

Comment: What is your question? Do you want to log all incoming requests? What version of spring boot do you use?

Comment: Spring boot 2.0.6. Sorry, my question is if that was the normal behavior. Successful GET requests are not logged?

Answer (score 0):

You can set the logging level of the Spring web package to `DEBUG` in the `application.properties`, something like:
`logging.level.org.springframework.web=debug` 
or in recent version of Spring Boot:
`logging.level.web=debug`